# Start Team Viewer on Windows 10 from a Linux PC on same network

Tags: windows-10, remote-access, teamviewer, ubuntu-server

I have a Win 10 machine that I had to remotely reboot. 
I also have an ubuntu server on the same network. 
Team Viewer hasn't auto signed in on Win 10 machine following the reboot and I need access to it. 
I can SSH into the Ubuntu box and can ping the Windows. Is there any means to cause the Win 10 to sign in to Teamviewer from here?

Comment: A round about way but can't you remote in using the normal windows remote desktop tool?

Comment: Unfortunately not, only port I have forwarded is SSH